# Nested loops writing with apply/lapply, etc

Tags: r

I am currently learning R, but I stumbled upon some problems, especially for-loops. I think it's not the best style to use loops in R but instead use apply/lapply etc. I am trying to create all possible pairs of sequences which differ exactly in one position. In every row I have 2 columns, from these two I extract the unique sequences. Then I compare each sequence with all other remaining sequences, and if they differ in exactly one position I add them to all_pairs. After I compared all sequences, I write all_pairs into a new column and go to the next row. The code works, but it is very slow, it takes about 10 minutes while using only 1% of my CPU. What would be the best way to improve the speed? I wrote down the first 5 lines of my data_filtered at the end of the code, together with the output of the first 2 lines. Any help is appreciated. Since this is my first post on Stackoverflow, don't hesitate to tell what what I can do better (formatting, etc.).

```
#Write function to compute string difference
string_diff <- function(string1, string2){
  return (sum(unlist(strsplit(string1,"")) != unlist(strsplit(string2, ""))))
}

for (row in 1:nrow(data_filtered)){
  #Get all unique sequences in a row
  UniqSeq <- unique(c(unlist(strsplit(data_filtered[row, "UniqueSeq"], "-")), data_filtered[row, "Seq8mer"]))
  all_pairs <- character()
  #Loop over all sequences and compair number of nucleotide differences
  for (first in 1:(length(UniqSeq)-1)){
    for (second in (first+1):length(UniqSeq)){
      str1 <- UniqSeq[first]
      str1_rev_comp <- paste(toupper(rev(comp(unlist(strsplit(str1, ""))))), collapse="")
      str2 <- UniqSeq[second]
      str2_rev_comp <- paste(toupper(rev(comp(unlist(strsplit(str2, ""))))), collapse="")
      #If only differ in 1 position, add to all_pairs
      if((string_diff(str1, str2) == 1) || (string_diff(str1_rev_comp, str2) == 1) || (string_diff(str1, str2_rev_comp) == 1) || (string_diff(str1_rev_comp, str2_rev_comp) == 1)){
        all_pairs <- c(all_pairs, paste(str1, str2, sep ="-"))
      }
    }
  }
  print(row)
  #Add all pairs to Pairs column
  data_filtered$Pairs[row] <- list(all_pairs)
}

data_filtered[c(1:5),c(1,2)]
                                      UniqueSeq  Seq8mer
6                    ACAAAAAT-ACAAAATT-ACAAAAGT ACAAAAAT
7                    AAAATCAC-AAAATTAC-AAAATCAT AAAATCAC
8  ATTTTCTA-TTTTTCTA-ATTTTCAA-ATCTTCTA-TTATTCTA ATTTTCTA
11                   AAGAAGAT-AAGAAGGT-AAGGAGAT AAGAAGAT
13                   ACAAAAAT-ACAAAATT-AGAAAATT ACAAAAAT

data_filtered[c(1,2),3]
[[1]]
[1] "ACAAAAAT-ACAAAATT" "ACAAAAAT-ACAAAAGT" "ACAAAATT-ACAAAAGT"

[[2]]
[1] "AAAATCAC-AAAATTAC" "AAAATCAC-AAAATCAT"
```